# r facet_wrap uneven number of plots, center bottom plot over x axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have an uneven number of plots in my facet_wrap, meaning I end up with only one plot on the final row. I would like this plot to be centered over the x-axis title, but have not been able to figure it out. Thankful for any help.

Simple example to illustrate my question and work with:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(head(diamonds, 50), aes(x = depth, y = price)) +
  geom_point()

p <- p + facet_wrap(~color, scales = "free", ncol = 3)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with facet wrap. Maybe with facet grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can shuffle things around in the gtable; unfortunately the names appear somewhat inconsistent

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

g$layout[grepl("panel-3-1", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] <- g$layout[grepl("panel-2-2", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] 
g$layout[grepl("axis-l-3-1", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] <- g$layout[grepl("axis-l-2-2", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] 
g$layout[grepl("axis-b-1-3", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] <- g$layout[grepl("axis-b-2-2", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] 
g$layout[grepl("strip-t-1-3", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] <- g$layout[grepl("strip-t-2-2", g$layout$name), c("l","r")] 

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something I can work with! I've encountered the concept of grobs when researching this, but I still don't really understand them. Do you have any suggestion on where I could learn more about manipulating them in R?

Comment: this particular question is more about gtable layouts, for which there is essentially no documentation. [This page might help a little](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/gtable)

Comment: @baptiste Has there been any advancement to the core ggplot2 functions that addresses this? It seems like such a fundamental action but all I've found are these rather hackish workarounds using other packages. I'm consistently frustrated that when ggplot doesn't do something I want it to the answer is to use the grob. I am woefully unfamiliar with them and would prefer not to burn the time to learn them! Sorry for the rant, appreciate any insights!